# Linear equations with one variable BASH script

Tags: bash

How can I solve  equations with just one variable like the following:

x + 3 = 5 x + 11

1 - 2x = 2x

2x - 7 = 18

Do I need to use expr or bc -l(as for example, `echo "$2 / $5"|bc -l`
I really have no idea although I know the basics of shell/bash
Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to solve each equation for x or find a least-squares solution for all three equation together?

Comment: the program should be able to solve at least those equations

Comment: Is not a system, just individual equations and need to solve for x in each one

Comment: and how are your equations formatted; do they have a fixed formatting style? otherwise it will be complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your equations are formatted in a fixed formatting style:

```
ax + b = 0
```

then you should use something like sed or bash variable manipulation to extract the variables `a` and `b`. After that you can use bc as you described:

```
echo " -$b / $a" | bc -l
```

NOTE that each linear equation in `x` can be rewritten as to match the `ax + b` format.

Comment: Ok let me try to write the code now, but that should do it, thanks!